# How to use a 'plotWidth' calculation to position a highcharts pie

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm currently using a combination of pie charts and stand alone SVG images in a chart but I have encountered a positioning problem with the pies. The pies are linked to each other and as the chart is resized, I want them to remain the exact distance away from each other. If you look at the example in the fiddles and resize the window bigger and smaller you will see that they travel apart as the window grows and clash when the window size is reduced.

To position the pies relative to each other, I wanted to do something like this so that they are +/- 50px from the 75% width of the plot area:

```
(this.plotWidth  * 0.75) - 50  //for the first pie
(this.plotWidth  * 0.75) + 50  //for the second pie
```

That way, no matter what size the window, the pair of pies will always sit together.

http://jsfiddle.net/so7k6w7v/1/

I tried to use this logic in `center`, however, the x position appears to be set to 0 [demonstrated in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/so7k6w7v/2/).

```
        series: [           
        {
            type: 'pie',
            //center: [(this.plotWidth * 0.75) - 50, 71], //for the first pie
            center: ['50%', 71],
            name: 'bbb',
            data: [
                ['', 40.5],
                ['', 59.5]
            ],
            innerSize: '60%',
            colors: ['#ff0000',"#f5f5f5"],
        },
        {
            type: 'pie',
            //center: [(this.plotWidth * 0.75) + 50, 71], //for the second pie
            center: ['65%', 128],
            name: 'aaa',
            data: [
                ['', 43.1],
                ['', 56.9]
            ],
            innerSize: '60%',
            colors: ["#555","#f5f5f5"],
        },
```

As an aside, the reason that I am using a pie this way instead of a `solidguage` is because of [bug #3947](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3947) which produces an error when used with other series types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this by editing the SVG object and calling the `redraw()` method on the pies.

```
function ChartLoad() {

var chart = this,
    centerX = chart.plotWidth  * 0.5,
    Pie1CenterX = centerX * 1.5;

var Pie1 = chart.get('Pie1');
         Pie1['chart']['plotLeft'] = Pie1CenterX;
         Pie1.redraw();

var Pie2 = chart.get('Pie2');
         Pie2['chart']['plotLeft'] = Pie1CenterX+90;
         Pie2.redraw();
}
```

This way, both pies are positioned relative to each other (Pie2 is +90 from Pie1) and as Pie1 is positioned exactly 75% along the x of the plot area they will always appear to be positioned next to each other, centred on the right side of the chart.

You can see it working here:
http://jsfiddle.net/so7k6w7v/3/

Comment: Although I have answered this, I am still open to suggestions on how to improve. Currently the pies are drawn (initially in the wrong place) and then repositioned and drawn again. I still would like to be able to get the correct position set from the start instead of updating it on the load/redraw events.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with your `center: []` elements and got them to be aligned vertical and horizontal:

```
    center: [71, 10],
    name: 'bbb',
```

and

```
    center: [200, 10],
    name: 'aaa',
```

Since I do not know how you want them positioned this is just a proof that you can have them not overlapping.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, however I'm afraid this doesn't quite solve the problem. The pies are just 2 of the elements in chart, there are an additional 2 which I create with raw SVG. What I want is the pies centred in the right side and the SVG centred on the left. When using fixed pixels, I can't get them centered on the right side for every possible screen resolution without first working out how wide the plot area is.